# Using GenFireServerEvent(('__commit;__redirect={/}')) in JQuery function on SP2010 Page

Tags: 2010, jquery

I have a custom Submit button on a custom NewItem form. I have a JQuery function which I would like to run when this button is clicked.

I also need the `GenFireServerEvent(('__commit;__redirect={/}'))` action to run after my function if certain things happen in the function.

Ideally I'd like to just use the `GenFireServerEvent(('__commit;__redirect={/}'))` action in my function so I can specify when to perform the action, however when I try this I get the "GenFireServerEvent is not defined" error.

Is there an alternative for `GenFireServerEvent(('__commit;__redirect={/}'))` to use in JQuery functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GenFireServerEvent is not a JavaScript function. If you look under the hood in the DOM, you'll see it gets rendered into a completely different. e.g.

```
<A style="WIDTH: 10px; DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 10px" href="javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_9254a69e_0546_4c53_ba5d_c155337d00e3$ctl02','__cancel;dvt_form_key={-1}')"><IMG style="POSITION: absolute; TOP: -128px !important; LEFT: 0px !important" border=0 alt=New src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"></A>
```

What you can do though, in your form's code is wrap the GenFireServerEvent with an if statement. This is a common task especially when using the PreSaveAction function.  Here's an example:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: if( PreSaveAction() ) {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')}" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Other solution, You can call the other function with other click using jquery, you need add an id for your input button.

```
 <input id="custom" type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onmousedown="javascript: if( PreSaveAction() ) {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')}" onmouseup="newEvent()"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">

   function newEvent(){
        alert("your code");
   }

 </script>
```

Comment: I'd love to have happy news about your final answer, but the sad part is that the onmouseup button event seems to work when IT wants to... what I need is to capture the onclick event using jQuery and inside the jquery function do:
1. submit the form data
2. redirect or do whatever the problem, however, is that the ddwrt:gen** code is not useful inside a js function or refuses to cooperate with the script at all....